# How to run Spring app on localhost without IntelliJ?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

My app works when run from IntelliJ but I have issues trying to run it without help of IntelliJ.

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class LoadingsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(LoadingsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl.margol</groupId>
    <artifactId>loadings</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>loadings</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=8087
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/loadings-db;
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

.war file was created and deployed in Tomcat Web Application Manager.
When I call `localhost:8080/loadings-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/start`
i get error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /loadings-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/start

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.20
```

I was trying to change port in application.properties file but it didn't help.
Can You help to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to add extends SpringBootServletInitializer to your LoaddingApplications class.

Comment: You don't need to extend **SpringBootServletInitializer**. If you have a blank line between **@SpringBootApplication** and your class declaration as in the code sample you have published, remove it. Then try command  **mvn spring-boot:run**. If you still have a problem, give a good read to [this doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-running-as-a-packaged-application)

Comment: @Johna mvn spring-boot:run only works when you run your app as standalone application (with embedded tomact).
He clearly mentioned that he is creating a war file and deploying in external tomact container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your application didn't deployed at all.

Since you are deploying your application as war file in external container you will need to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer`.
Your class will look like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LoadingApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(HelloServerApplication.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) 
{
    return builder.sources(HelloServerApplication.class);
}
}
```

Why are you using this dependency:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

You don't need it or mark it's scope as `provided`

Also you may need to exclude tomcat from `spring-boot-starter-web`like this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
          <exclusions>
            <exclusion> 
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
          </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And Since you are using external container `server.port=8087` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class LoadingsApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(LoadingsApplication.class, args);
 }

}
```

Comment: You don't have to extend **SpringBootServletInitializer** when you have annotated your main class with **@SpringBootApplication**